# .Net Standard project with nugets build target

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I am using:

```
dotnet pack MyProject.csproj
```

for creating nuget netstandard/net462 packages and it works fine for simple use cases.

How do I configure MyProject.csproj to include files in the "build" nuget level?
Or can I add reference to nuspec file from .csproj ?

This is how it would be in .nuspec file:

```
<package>
    <files>
        <file src="Libs\*.*" target="build" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tag in csproj that points to the nuspec file to be used instead of the csproj:

```
  <NuspecFile>MyLibrary.nuspec</NuspecFile>
  <NuspecProperties>version=$(Version);id=$(AssemblyName)</NuspecProperties>
```